# How can I send an id over the url?

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting

I need to send an id that I am going to collect and use in a plugin. Plugin will collect it in a page where I use plugins shortcode. The url I am trying to get is like www.example.com/device/devicename-id. Any idea on how can I do this?

Comment: Have you considered using [`add_rewrite_endpoint`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint), for example?

Comment: What about basic POST and GET methods to pass variable values as parameters?

Comment: @unifiedac GET and POST works but that is not what I am after.

Comment: @birgire Thanks. add_rewrite_endpoint worked for me but not the exact thing I wanted. I managed to get /device/devicename/id with add_rewrite_endpoint. Then I used add_rewrite_rule with. I managed to get /device/device-name-id. Thanks.